# Azure queue delete rest API returning "No Content" while delete API is working fine

Tags: azure, api, rest, queue

I'm working with rest delete API. It is working fine but its returning **No Content** in every success response. I have given too much time but problem is still persist. Could you please correct me where I am wrong with code. I searched and implemented same but I don't know at what point I am making mistake.

```
public static string DeleteMessage(String queueName, string popreceipt, string messageid)
        {
            string requestMethod = "DELETE";
           
            String urlPath = String.Format("{0}/messages/{1}?popreceipt={2}", queueName, Uri.EscapeDataString(messageid), Uri.EscapeDataString(popreceipt));

            String storageServiceVersion = "2017-11-09";
            String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
                    "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
                    dateInRfc1123Format,
                    storageServiceVersion);
            //String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", StorageAccountName, urlPath);
            String canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/messages/{2}\npopreceipt:{3}", StorageAccountName, queueName, messageid, popreceipt);
            String stringToSign = String.Format(
                    "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
                    requestMethod,
                    canonicalizedHeaders,
                    canonicalizedResource);
            String authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign);

            Uri uri = new Uri("https://" + StorageAccountName + ".queue.azure.com/" + urlPath);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = requestMethod;
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);

            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                return response.StatusCode.ToString();

            }
        }

public static String CreateAuthorizationHeader(String canonicalizedString)
        {
            String signature = String.Empty;

            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageAccountKey)))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0} {1}:{2}",
                "SharedKey",
                StorageAccountName,
                signature
            );

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `Delete Message` operation is supposed to return no content. From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-message2#status-code):

> ### Status code
>
> A successful operation returns status code 204 (No
> Content).

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [Gaurav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69345615/1945525): deleting a message is **not the same** as getting or dequeuing a message. What would you expect calling `DELETE` to return?

According to [MDN (DELETE - responses)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE#responses):

> If a DELETE method is successfully applied, there are several response status codes possible:
>
> - A 202 (Accepted) status code if the action will likely succeed but has not yet been enacted.
> - A 204 (No Content) status code if the action has been enacted and no further information is to be supplied.
> - A 200 (OK) status code if the action has been enacted and the response message includes a representation describing the status.